# How to Call c++ structure, typedef in dll and pass value from C# with delegate

Tags: c#, c++, dll, delegates, structure

My Strcuture is

```
struct Address{
char Name[4096];   
char Address[4096];
char Description[1024];

} ;
```

and Typedef for the Strcuture

```
typedef struct Address* (*__cdecl pgetAdd) ();
```

I pass pass the value to type

```
pgetAdd getStat = (pgetAdd)GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),"getStat"); 
char *Argv[] = { "Karthik", "23", "Chennai", "04-04-1984"}; 
getStat = (pgetAdd) startTest(Argv);
Address *mydata;
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata>Name); 
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata>Address); 
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata> Description);
```

And this contains the c++ dll

And I need to call the dll from c#

and I tried like

My Strcuture is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

public struct Address
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public string Name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public string Address;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string Description;
}
```

I used Typedef like this

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public delegate IntPtr getStatDelegate();
```

i Import the dll like this

```
[DllImport(@"E:\\EmployeeData.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "startTest", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe static extern IntPtr startTest ([In] IntPtr argv);
```

My code is

```
 IntPtr args= StringArrayToIntPtr<byte>(new string[] {  "Karthik", "23", "Chennai", "04-04-1984" });
 IntPtr ptr = startTest(args);  
 getStatDelegate getStat = (getStatDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(getStatDelegate));

 IntPtr structPtr = new IntPtr();
 structPtr= getStat();

 Address data = (Address)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, typeof(Address));

 richTextBox1.Text = data.Name;

 richTextBox2.Text = data.Address;

 richTextBox3.Text = data.Description;


 public static IntPtr StringArrayToIntPtr<GenChar>(string[]
 InputStrArray) where GenChar : struct
 {
     int size = InputStrArray.Length;
     IntPtr[] InPointers = new IntPtr[size];
     int dim = IntPtr.Size * size;
     IntPtr rRoot = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(dim);
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         if (typeof(GenChar) == typeof(char))
         {
             InPointers[i] = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(InputStrArray[i]);
         }
         else if (typeof(GenChar) == typeof(byte))
         {
             InPointers[i] = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(InputStrArray[i]);
         }
     }
     Marshal.Copy(InPointers, 0, rRoot, size);
     return rRoot;
}
```

My Ouput is

```
richTextBox1.Text = data.Name= Karthik;
richTextBox2.Text = data.Address= chennai;
richTextBox3.Text = data.Description=Welcome to our team something in dll;
```

---

i didn't get the output please correct the code as well help to find the solutions

Thanks you genius in advance

---

**

Comment: Your unmanaged code is not clear. Why getStat is assigned twice? What is startTest? Why uninitialized mydata is used?

Comment: As @Alex wrote, the C++ code doesn't make sense, please fix it to include your actual code if you want to get any reasonable suggestions. Additionally, it looks like `getStat` in `hGetProcIDDLL` is simply a function which accepts no parameters and returns a `Address*`. Is that correct? Can you add the C++ signature for that function? And what is `startSIPSessionint` in the C# DLLimport declaration? Is that supposed to be the same function?  The way your C# code is written right now is like `startSIPSessionint` returns a function pointer?

Comment: Yes @Groo it returns Address* , I have only Dll i dont have c++ signature,,,

Comment: And what's `startSIPSessionint`? This doesn't exist at all in your C++ example? Shouldn't you only have `Address *mydata = getStat();` in your C++ snippet?

Comment: Sorry it is startTest

Comment: @Groo ,I fine syntax for dllimport syntax in google , that y i put the entrypoint as function name

Comment: 1) what is `hGetProcIDDLL`/`getStat`? You assign the result of `GetProcAddress` (which gets the address of `getStat` from `hGetProcIDDLL`) to a variable named `getStat`. 2) What is `startTest` in your C++ example? You assign the result of calling `startTest(args)` to that same `getStat` variable. 3) Where do you pass `mydata` anyway? Please post your actual working C++ code. 4) in C#, you suddenly use `EmployeeData.dll`/`startTest`. Where's the equivalent in C++?

Comment: @Groo 1)  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("E:\\EmployeeData.dll")); so hGetProcIDDLL is dll library name ... 2) startTest in a function if pass the arguments it returns the address of the arguments 3)getStatDelegate getStat = (getStatDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(getStatDelegate));
structPtr= getStat();
 Address data = (Address)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, typeof(Address)); 
//getStatDelegate is Delegate function name

Comment: Please edit the question, your last comment is unreadable.